# how to comparing dataset to new data coming every week using SQL in Databricks

Tags: sql, databricks-sql

I want to find the number of ids changing their value every week and month

every week a new dataset get entered into the database, every week same ids are added with their values, some weeks values for some ids change.

I want to find the amount of ids change per month and week for all the data I have over the last 2 years.

all of this is being done in databricks

I have attached an example data-set, where data is entered for 3 ids for two months and 2 ids changed their value. the desired output shows what I need is that the second month showing 2 changes and the first showing 0 changes.

dataset

[image]

output needed

[image]

Comment: Join to adjacent month and different values. Simple group by at that point.

Comment: @shawnt00 you mean inner join? how would you do it to adjacent month? is there a funtion

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/add_months.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN` clause to adjacent month and different values and apply GROUP BY clause. On the resulting dataset apply the `add_months` function.

`add_months(startDate, numMonths)`

The `startDate` will take your Date and `numMonth` will take the values from the resulting GROUP BY clause.